# fscanf read access segfault

Tags: c, ubuntu, file-io, scanf

I a successfully open a file that contains initial key-value pairs. The code looks like this:

```
char key_tmp[30];
int value_tmp, status_index;

FILE *ZMU_Init_fd = NULL;
ZMU_Init_fd = fopen("zmu/zmu.cfg", "r");

if(ZMU_Init_fd ==  NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file");
    strerror(errno);
}

printf("key tmp is %s, value tmp is %d\n", key_tmp, value_tmp);
fscanf(ZMU_Init_fd, "%s %s", key_tmp, (char *)value_tmp);
printf("key tmp is %s, value tmp is %d\n", key_tmp, value_tmp);
```

When I run i get:

```
key tmp is y? value tmp is 1
```

then it segfaults. When I change access to "w" the code sets zmu.cfg file size to 0 and i get:

```
key tmp is y? value tmp is 1
key tmp is y? value tmp is 1
```

no segfault... Interestingly enough, once the file is 0 bytes I can change the access back to "r" it no longer segfaults and i get:

```
key tmp is y? value tmp is 1
key tmp is y? value tmp is 1
```

I believe this has something to do with the way fscanf works. Does fscanf delete the line from the file when it scans? All I am trying to do is get a key-value pair from a text file. I dont think i can use fread because the keys dont always have the same size. I do NOT want the file modified, any thoughts?

zmu.cfg looks like this:

```
MessageNum= message50
MsgInitOne= 0x01
MsgInitTwo= 0x04
MsgInitThree= 0x01

MessageNum= message50
VarOne= 0x02
VarTwo= 0x01

MessageNum= message50
MsgValOne= 0x01
MsgValTwo= 0x04
MsgValThree= 0x02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `key_tmp` before using it here.

```
printf("key tmp is %s, value tmp is %d\n", key_tmp, value_tmp);
```

You are passing the wrong argument to `fscanf`. Casting `value_tmp` to `char*` does not enable it to hold a string.

```
fscanf(ZMU_Init_fd, "%s %s", key_tmp, (char *)value_tmp);
```

If the file contains an integer, use:

```
fscanf(ZMU_Init_fd, "%s %d", key_tmp, &value_tmp);
```

If the file contains a string, make sure that `value_tmp` is a string large enough to hold the data.

```
char value_temp[1000];
```

and then, use:

```
fscanf(ZMU_Init_fd, "%s %s", key_tmp, value_tmp);
```

Comment: The key-value for MessageNum is just a placeholder for people who may edit this file in the future, almost like a comment. 
I really only care about the hex values. I think i can do  something like: fscanf(ZMU_Init_fd, "%s %s", key_tmp, key_tmp); I will update and re-post.

Comment: If you do that, you are most likely going to get the key overwritten by the value.

Comment: For the first line I was going to scrap the key-value pair anyway, the issue was definitely not passing the address of value_tmp. Did my question get down voted because I didnt initialize values? Getting down-voted highly discourages me from asking questions on SO.

Comment: @MeganB, I don't know why your question got downvoted. SO is full of cowards that don't bother to explain why they downvoted a question or an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You experience **undefined behavior** on your first call to:

```
printf("key tmp is %s, value tmp is %d\n", key_tmp, value_tmp);
```

Neither `key_tmp` or `value_tmp` are initialized to any value. After you attempt to access the uninitialized values, all bets are off. Your code could give you some output, or it could segfault -- you are experiencing **undefined behavior** -- anything could happen.

Further, if you are reading an `int` in `value_tmp`, your `fscanf` format string should be:

```
fscanf(ZMU_Init_fd, "%s %d", key_tmp, &value_tmp);
```

Comment: I dont really care about the values on the first printf, i just printed them to see if they change.

Comment: @MeganB after you enter the realm of **undefined behavior** your code cannot be relied on for anything. You may get a proper value, it may complete without issue or it may segfault and crash. The operation of your code from that point is simply **undefined**.

Comment: Good point, I should have initialized either way. I will shy away from this sort of thing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yay! I changed the last lines to this:

```
fscanf(ZMU_Init_fd, "%s %s", key_tmp, key_tmp);
printf("key tmp is %s, value tmp is %d\n", key_tmp, value_tmp);
fscanf(ZMU_Init_fd, "%s %x", key_tmp, &key_tmp);
printf("key tmp is %s, value tmp is %d\n", key_tmp, value_tmp);
```

and I get:

```
key tmp is message50 value tmp is 8388608
key tmp is MsgInitOne value tmp is 1
```

Thanks for looking at my code, didn't think i needed to pass the address of key_tmp to fscanf for %i since I did not have to for %s.